# Best practices to fix an over-minimalized question?

Tags: discussion

I have [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61596064/sql-index-on-join-and-group-by/61596150#61596150).

Based on the [minimal working example principle](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I took care to chop out everything from my production code that was irrelevant to the problem.  Unfortunately, I chopped out too much, and the resulting problem had a trivial workaround.  In the usual race to post answers, an answer was posted that correctly solved the problem.

Now, if I fix the question, then it will make the given answer incorrect.  If I post another question, it will only differ by a single line of code.

What would be the best course of action in such circumstances?

Comment: Ask a new question. That is the only way not to invalidate the answer. Make sure that you explain well what the difference to your last question is and why the answer there doesn't work for your extended problem to prevent it from being closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

In this case your example *wasn't* a **minimum** reproducible example.

You should post another question, as editing your current question risks it being reverted now that it's answered.

Next time change your SQL query to use columns from both tables that are not foreign keys, such that the JOIN is still required.